# How to get LinkedIn Updates detail from it "updateKey"?

Tags: ios, linkedin-api, social-networking, ios8.1

I got following JSON from https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/network/updates

```
(
    {
        isCommentable = 0;
        isLikable = 0;
        timestamp = "-1";
        updateContent =         {
          ........
        };
        updateKey = "UPDATE-c2858344-12394303";
        updateType = CMPY;
    }
     ,......
)
```

In above all the array JSON,`updateKey` is unique like any ID.

I need to show Linkedin Update URL based on this unique `updateKey` to show it in webview of `iOS` application.

I try to found this in LinkedIn api But I not found proper solution.

Thanks in advance.